# PowerShell: DEL command to delete files in subfolder

Tags: command-line, powershell

I have huge folder and inside it I have a lot of sub folder inside subfolder and I wrote this Command for deleting files in subfolder and I want to do the same thing with an script PowerShell.

For example:

```
del /F /S /Q "C:\QQQ\*.RAW"
```

[image: click here to see the image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get-childitem -path C:\QQQ -include *.raw -recurse | remove-item`

Comment: [Since PowerShell v3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-3.0), the use of `-Filter` instead of `-Include` should be considered when only searching for one specific file-type, as it may improve performance significantly.

Comment: @flolilolilo I agree. But I've been burnt too many times trying to run my scripts on default Windows 7 installs.

Comment: Worth mentioning `-WhatIf`, which can be added to the end of cmdlets to know what would happen if you were to execute the command without actually executing it. Great for learning, and especially great when verifying the structure of a `Remove-Item` command.